# how to pass a date argument in a job spark using oozie

Tags: apache-spark, workflow, jobs, oozie

I need to pass a date in my

**workflow.xml**

```
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>yarn</master>
        <mode>cluster</mode>
        <name>Spark-workflow</name>
        <class>Main</class>
        <jar>${nameNode}/user/my_jar.jar</jar>
        <spark-opts>
          --executor-memory 1G 
          --num-executors 4 
          --executor-cores 3
        </spark-opts>
        <arg>--date 2017/02/01</arg>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Workflow failed, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
    </message>
</kill>
```

**job.properties**

```
 nameNode=hdfs://10.26.20.40:8020
 jobTracker=10.26.20.40:8021
 oozie.use.system.libpath=true
 oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://10.26.20.40:8020/user/workflow.xml
 outputDir=mydir
```

but when i lunch the spark job with

oozie job -oozie http://.../oozie -config /home/job.properties -run

i have the error below :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.isInInterpreter()Z
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeIfNecessary(Logging.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.log(ApplicationMaster.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

so, please how can i pass a date in a spark job using oozie?

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution ?

Comment: I don’t understand the issue here. The error is saying `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. Is this really a date issue?